# How to break a long line of arguments into several short lines?

Tags: robotframework, line-breaks

Example:

```
Log To Console   This is the first argument   This is the second argument   This is the third argument
```

How can I break a line with multiple short arguments?

I tried using `\` or just breaking the lines (without using any special characters) but it didn't work.

Edit: To clarify - I want to provide arguments to a keyword in multiple lines. I want to physically split one long line of source code into multiple short lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dividing-test-data-to-several-rows):

> If there is more data than readily fits a row, it possible to use ellipsis (...) to continue the previous line.

```
    Example test     [Documentation]    Documentation   for this    test case.
                     ...      This can get  quite   long...
                     Do X     one       two     three
                     ...      four      five    six
```

Comment: This works fine but only for case 1). But I decided to split my question into 2 separate ones so I accept this answer.